Cloud Run Failed to update or delete existing services
I'm encountering an issue with Cloud Run. I'm unable to update, create, or delete services. The error message I receive is: "Deletion in progress. Resource readiness deadline exceeded....failed."
I've checked the service health for the region, and there are no reported problems.
Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how to resolve it?
I tried using : CLI (gcloud) and UI (Console).
Thank you.

According to the error message you provided while deleting your Cloud Run service, it requires appropriate tools to handle this kind of problem, so you need help from the Cloud Run engineering team as mentioned in this documentation.  You can get in touch with them via Google Cloud support.
Also, make sure you have not disabled Cloud run Api.
You may also file this as a bug so that they could check this one out on their end.

Unfortunately, the customer support you suggest is paid, and I don't have that option. I find it unfortunate that we have to pay for a problem that originates from the GCP platform. Additionally, using the issue tracker takes a lot of time to get a response.
I can confirm that the Cloud Run API is active on the project because I used it to create the service.
The problem resolved itself, after 24hours.
